# Iterate through df and update based on prediction

Tags: python, pandas

I am not a Python programmer, so am struggling with the following;

```
def py_model(df):
    import pickle
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from pandas import Series,DataFrame
    
    filename = 'C:/aaaTENNIS-DATA/votingC.pkl'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
         ab = row[['abc','def','ghi','jkl']]
         input = np.array(ab)
         df['Prediction'] =pd.DataFrame(loaded_model.predict([input]))
         df['AccScore'] =??
    
    return df
```

For each row of the dataframe, I wish to get a prediction and put it in `df['Prediction']` and also get the model score and put it in another field.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question exactly? You can [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask]. Is the problem that you're overwriting `df['Prediction']` on every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate

```py
import pickle

filename = 'C:/aaaTENNIS-DATA/votingC.pkl'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
df['Prediction'] = loaded_model.predict(df[['abc','def','ghi','jkl']])
```

Tip #1: don't use `input` as a variable, it's a built-in function in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Tip #2: don't put `import` statement in a function, put them all at the beginning of your file

Comment: Many thanks, tried it and it worked fine (just with extra ']'. How do I get the score from the prediction? Thank you.

Comment: Depends on what your score is.

Comment: I was trying to use something like    GBC_best1 = gsGBC1.best_estimator_   or 
gsGBC1.best_score_  (my model is a gradient booster)

Comment: OK, no problem then. Yes, you solved my issues. Thank you !